# getting clang-llvm to work

Tags: linux, llvm-clang

I am trying to get clang to work at all.. I am re-learning some of Linux again.. 
So, If this question is too basic, I apologize..
Here is what I have..
I have a Dell 2 core computer, with a Solid State Drive that I have Fedora 20 (x86-64) on..
I have Downloaded the pre-built clang-llvm file for Fedora 20..
I have extracted it to my LLVM Folder..
I have cd'ed to the clang bin folder, where all the bin files for clang are at.. (In Terminal mode)
I have tried out some of the commands in this bin folder such as clang, clang++ and clang-check.. None of them work..
Bash "says" they are not there, but when I do a list or a dir they 'do' show up..
So How do I make these clang /bin commands accessible to bash or work without bash complaining ??

THANK YOU Marty

Comment: have you setup your environment variables ?

Answer (score 1):

The LLVM suite source code must be configured via the configure script.

This script sets variables in the various *.in files, most notably `llvm/Makefile.config` and `llvm/include/Config/config.h`. It also populates OBJ_ROOT with the Makefiles needed to begin building LLVM.

To configure LLVM, follow these steps:

Change directory into the object root directory:

> % cd OBJ_ROOT

Do I use export or something else so the program knows where to find OBJ_ROOT and the same for SRC_ROOT ??

I have my tree arranged as follows --
llvm (then under that) clang+llvm and clang-tools, etc..
llvm is my root directory which somehow needs to be made equivalent to SRC_ROOT and that is what I DON'T know how to do..
once I know how to set SRC_ROOT I then can find where OBJ_ROOT needs to be located and then set that, once that is done, then the scripts should run..
I know I can edit the make and configure files directly to the path that I want it to be set to, but I might not get them all set..

Run the configure script located in the LLVM source tree:

> % SRC_ROOT/configure --prefix=/install/path [other options]

Options and references can be found here : http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/docs/GettingStarted.html#config

Overall guide and setup information which will have everything you need is here :

http://llvm.org/releases/3.4.1/docs/GettingStarted.htm

Take it step by step and you'll be fine.

Thank You, I got the clang commands to work, after getting my old linux book out and typing the PATH for the clang bin files.. So that is now ok..
Thanks for the links, I have tried to follow them, but they seem to assume that I know how to do what they want me to do without telling me How to do it..
THANK YOU Marty